# Help with CSS positioning

Tags: asp.net, css

This is my page:
[link](http://aspspider.info/yevis/Comments.aspx)

As you can see on the screen shot, the icons (red circle) are not aligned with icons above it (click on title to expand it).
[alt text http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/1390/35070527.jpg](http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/1390/35070527.jpg)

The CSS:

```
body
{
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-Serif;
}


#talkbacks .noshow
{
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
    padding: 2px 10px;

}


#talkbacks ul.top
{
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    margin: 0 -1px;
}

#talkbacks li
{
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top: 5px;*/
}
/*
#talkbacks ul
{

    clear: both;
}*/



.n
{
    color: #758888;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    line-height: 15px;
    width:15px; 
}


.c
{
    float: left;
    /*width: 400px;    */
    width:92%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right:5px;

}

.d
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #758888;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


ul
{
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    clear:both;
}
a
{
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;

}

a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #284D99;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
a:hover, a:active
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}


li ul li div.c
{
    padding-left: 26px;
}
li ul li ul li div.c
{
    padding-left: 52px;

}
li ul li ul li ul li div.c
{
    padding-left: 77px;
}
li ul li ul li ul li ul li div.c
{
    padding-left: 104px;
}

#talkbacks .noshow .userpanel
{
    display: none;  
}

#talkbacks .noshow .adminpanel
{
    display:none;
}
#talkbacks .noshow div.CommentBody, .show div.CommentBody p
{
    display: none;

}

/***************    Show Comment   **********************/
#talkbacks .show
{
    background: #F3F3F3 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B6C7C7;
    border-top: 1px solid #B6C7C7;
    display: table;
    font-size: 12px;

    padding: 11px 10px;
    width: 439px;

}
/*#talkbacks .show p
{
    font-size: 1em;
}*/
#talkbacks .show div.CommentBody, .show div.CommentBody p
{
    display: block;
    margin: 1.5px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#talkbacks .show .userpanel
{

    margin-top: 10px;

    display:block;
}


#talkbacks .show .userpanel .votes div.voteResult
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    color: #555555;
    float:left;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#talkbacks .show .userpanel div.reply
{
    float:left;
}

#talkbacks .show .userpanel .votes div.buttons
{
    float:left;

}

/*************************** Add new comment **********************************/
#NewComment .textBox
{
    border: 1px Solid #002080;
    overflow:auto;
}
.linka 
{  
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}
```

The problematic part is this one(i think):

```
li ul li div.c
{
    padding-left: 26px;
}
li ul li ul li div.c
{
    padding-left: 52px;

}
```

I want to move the div "c", to the right without shifing the userpanel with the icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this a easy way.

```
<div class="commentcontainer">
......
<div class="updown">....</div>
......
</div>

style :

.commentcontainer{position:relative;}
.commentcontainer .updown {position:absolute; top:20px; right:20px;}
```

this should work. sorry i used other classes and stuff.. 
the main ideea is: put position:relative; in the css of the commentbox and put  position:absolute; top:20px; right:20px; in the css of the up/down vote this should put your  up/down vote img`s in the same spot in all comments.

Or if this does not work you should check the width of the commentbox`s if it has a defined value.. try to put : width:100%;
Hope it helps

Comment: If you just want the ratings in the bottom left corner all the time, absolute positioning is what I would use too. +1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are setting the width to 92% of its container then adding 52px of padding onto that. That is making the layout something like this:

```
|26px| LEVEL 1 |
|    |   92%   |

|  52px  | LEVEL 2 |
|        |   92%   |
```

As the icons are aligned to the right, they are now offset as the right edge is further across. I would recommend not setting the width of the div and instead using margins to align them, something like this:

```
|26px| LEVEL 1 |
|    |         |

| 52px  | LVL2 |
|       |      |
```

As a tip for debugging these sorts of issue, put borders on everything of different colours. This would probably have made what is happening more obvious as you would "see" it.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in FF3

```
#talkbacks .show
{   
  -moz-background-clip:border;
  -moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
  -moz-background-origin:padding;
  background:#F3F3F3 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #B6C7C7;
  border-top:1px solid #B6C7C7;
  font-size:12px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:11px 10px;
  position:relative;
  width:439px;
}

div.votes
{
  float:none !important;
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
}
```